# How can i reposition a sub ul in a responsive web site

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm developing a responsive website and I'm having a little problem with the menu. I'll show the images below to be easier to understand what is happening ...

The menu on a desktop is shown as follows:

[image]

And in a mobile device it should be shown as follows:

[image]

And currently my code is rendered as follows:

[image]

I wish the sub menu was loaded under the menu when rendered on a mobile device, any suggestions how to do it?

Here is my html code:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li>
        <ul id="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Todas as categorias</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Logo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Campanha</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Print</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Digital</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Indoor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projetos Especiais</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Trabalhe Conosco</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Quem Somos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Prêmios</a></li>
    <li><a class="select" href="#">Contato</a></li>
</ul>
```

The Css code for desktop:

```
#menu{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0 0;
    float: right;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    text-align: left;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
#menu li{
    list-style: none;
}
#menu li a{
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'swiss921_btregular';
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 32px;
    color: #231f20;
}
#menu li a:hover{
    color: #ed1d24;
}
#menu li #sub-menu li a{
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 34px;
    font-family: 'swiss921_btregular';
}
#menu li a.select{
    color: #ed1d24;
}
```

And the actual Css code for mobile:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 768px){
    #menu{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 50px auto;
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #menu li{
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 13px;
    }
    #menu li #sub-menu li a{
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

I have fiddle it: http://jsfiddle.net/r3zeB/

That's basically it, hope someone can help me and sorry for my bad english. Thank you.

Comment: first time seeing someone asking for horizontal menu in mobile view :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always place another copy of your sub menu where you want it to be on mobile. Then use a `display:none;` for it to be shown only when you want it and to hide the other one.

This is maybe not the proper way to do it but it would definitely works

Comment: Yes, use medias queries to hide/show the one you want

Comment: Understand it, so i just duplicate the sub menu? Instead of just one html structure i place two of them.

Comment: @CaioKawasaki that's really a bad idea. you can have single menu, use media queries to detect screen size and change the visual representation